# Foxpro-style app with database in using Python

Tags: python, database

Well, I don't know if this is the place to ask this, but I'm sure here I will have an answer more easily than in any other StackExchange site.

A few years ago, a teacher was teaching me FoxPro, and it was awesome because I could make database driven apps, like accountancy software, but after Microsoft finished with its development, I don't want to continue using a kinda "old" language with no official support, so, now that I'm learning more Python, I want to know if there is a easy way to make foxpro like apps with python, using databases, and if any of you can help me with some info and tutorials about this.

Thanks.

Comment: While python is certainly capable of using a database, this question is far too broad, and asks for an off-site recommendation, which means it's off-topic.

Comment: @IanMcLaird (and presumably others confused): this question is over a year old and is only on the front page because of a stupid edit to fix a spelling error in the title. VTC or moderate, but I doubt the OP is still interested in this tumbleweed.

Comment: @davejagoda Please don't do this. Not only is it completely pointless to fix spelling errors in abandoned posts from last year, you don't even have 2K rep so someone has to come behind you and 'approve' this! Please make your edits count!